# Redux middleware change state before next()

Tags: javascript, redux, middleware, react-redux

I would like to modify the state before `next()` is called so every reducer applied after the middleware gets the new state. **Is it possible? How?**

The only idea that comes to my mind is very hacky and would be something like this:

```
export const myMiddleware = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
    const oldReducer = ????
    store.replaceReducer(myReducer);
    store.dispatch(action);
    const newState = store.getState();
    store.replaceReducer(oldReducer);
    return next(newState);
}
```

As I haven't seen any method to get the current reducer, it should be given to the middleware in any manner:

```
export const myMiddleware = (oldReducer) => (store) => (next) => (action) => {
   ...
}

const store = createStore(originalReducer, applyMiddleware(myMiddleware(originalReducer)));
```

Which seems even more hacky!

The main purpose is to build a package that maps an action object (`action.payload`) and a path (`action.meta`) in store `state`. In this scenario, the reducer is distributed in an npm package, so it should be "chained" somehow. So right now the reducer is detecting if there is a path and an object inside payload, and tries to reduce the new state from it.

The worst solution is to instruct the user to call the reducer from their own reducer, just before any other action inside the reducer. This is not a solid pattern. So at first, I was thinking in an as much agnostic as possible middleware that automatically does the work. And that's why I'm trying to modify state from middleware if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to be calling individual reducers from within middleware. It sounds like you're condensing what should be multiple sequential actions into a single action, which is what's causing you problems. If you use something like [redux-saga](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/) to manage chains of actions, you can likely accomplish what you're looking for pretty easily.

Here's a basic example of managing a sequence of actions with redux-saga:

```
import { takeEvery } from 'redux-saga'
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

export function * watchForSomeAction () {
  // Every time SOME_ACTION is dispatched, doSomethingElse() will be called
  // with the action as its argument
  yield * takeEvery('SOME_ACTION', doSomethingElse)
}

export function * doSomethingElse (action) {
  // put() is redux-saga's way of dispatching actions
  yield put({ type: 'ANOTHER_ACTION', payload: action.payload })
}
```

This example simply watches for `SOME_ACTION`, and when it happens, it dispatches `ANOTHER_ACTION`. With something like this, you can ensure that `ANOTHER_ACTION`'s reducers are dealing with the new state resulting from `SOME_ACTION`'s reducers.

Comment: Thanks, the situation I'm facing is that I'm building a package that maps an action object (`payload`) and a path (`action.meta`) in an `immutable-js` `state`. In this scenario, the reducer is distributed in a package, so it should be "chained" somehow. At first thought I was thinking in a as much agnostic as possible middleware. So that's why I'm trying to modify state from middleware if possible.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Would it make sense to simply dispatch an action from within your middleware then? Your package users would have to add your package's reducer to their combineReducers(), but that's normal for packages that modify state. Or am I misunderstanding your goal?

Comment: You are right, this is not the goal. If the user adds the package reducer, it will not be able to modify the whole reducer, and this is the intention: construct a helper function that modifies the user state before the user continues with their actions. Would be a kind of `express node.js` middleware that parses the params before the next middleware/user function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding. Can you provide an example of your desired API and desired outcome?

Comment: Ok, now I can send the link to what I'm trying to achive: https://github.com/appfeel/path-reducer I will also ask in redux repo, as I've been looking inside redux code and it seems there is no solution at this moment